# Accses json data from API to frontend Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api

I want to make an app that reminds you when your insurance expires, and I want to access data from my database to make an edit form and have the fields populated with those data. I have this function in InsurancesController:

```
public function edit($insurance)
{
    $insurance = Insurance::whereId($insurance)->first();

    return response() -> json([
        'insurance' => $insurance
    ]); 
}
```

I have this route :

```
<Route path="/:id/edit" exact render={props => (
     <EditInsurance {...props} insurances={this.state.insurances} />)}
 />
```

and I have this component, just for testing:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class EditInsurances extends Component {
  render() {
    const { insurances } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Hello</p>
        {insurances.map(insurance => (
          <p>{insurance.id}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default EditInsurances;
```

How do i access just the insurance that I want to edit?

**Edit**

This is what i get when i use postman to: reminderapi.test/api/insurances/5/edit :

```
{
    "insurance": {
        "id": 5,
        "user_id": 1,
        "tip": "Asigurare",
        "date_exp": "1975-12-28",
        "date_notif": "2006-06-19",
        "note": "Vitae dolorem corporis impedit eligendi laborum quidem.",
        "created_at": "2019-03-11 09:49:23",
        "updated_at": "2019-03-11 09:49:23"
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to be clearer on your doubt. Post more details.

Comment: I want to access the data that i send in the controller (json) to my edit route

Comment: Can you post what data you are sending on the request ?

Comment: This is what i get when i use postman to: reminderapi.test/api/insurances/5/edit :
`{
    "insurance": {
        "id": 5,
        "user_id": 1,
        "tip": "Asigurare",
        "date_exp": "1975-12-28",
        "date_notif": "2006-06-19",
        "note": "Vitae dolorem corporis impedit eligendi laborum quidem.",
        "created_at": "2019-03-11 09:49:23",
        "updated_at": "2019-03-11 09:49:23"
    }
}`

Comment: I updated the post so it is easier to read

Comment: try changing your controller edit() method to this :

    `public function edit(Request $request) {
       $insurance_request = json_decode($request->get('insurance'));

       $insurance = Insurance::find($insurence_request->id);
       return response()->json($insurance)
    }`

Comment: to use the code above, make sure you have `use Illuminate\Http\Request` on the top of yout controller.

Comment: Is this the only thing that i should change? If so, it didn't change anything...

Comment: Now you can access correctly the data sent to the controller, can't you ? What response is Postman showing to you ?

Comment: Trying to get property 'id' of non object

Comment: But the data that i got from postman, was correct in first place

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, i thought you doubt was about not being able to get the data on back-end. I messed it up.

Comment: It's ok, thank you anyway. Any help is welcome :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take from route ID of Insurance which you want to edit.

Then iterate through all insurances and compare with ID from route.

```
class EditInsurances extends Component {
  render() {
    const { insurances } = this.props;
    // get from url-route ID 
    const insuranceId = this.props.match.params.id;

    const insurance = insurances.map(insurance => insurance.id === insuranceId)

    return (
      <div>
        <p>Hello</p>
        {insurance}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i get this : `Line 8:  'insurances' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: You should get from props insurances like this, right? 
const { insurances } = this.props;

Comment: I updated answer with const { insurances } = this.props; 
Try now.

Comment: I don't get any errors now, but it only displays the 'Hello' message

Comment: console.log('insuranceId', insuraceId) and console.log('insurances', insurances)
Console log them before return()
To check does we get list of insurances and how that list looks. 
And if we get that list. 
We need to know does we have insuraceId from "route", proubly that is problem. 
let me know what value you get.

Comment: I get all the insurances, but for insuranceId, i just get {insuranceId}, not a number

Comment: can you console log also this.props.match.params.id; and let me know what you get

Comment: I think the problem is on my show page. To get to the edit page i have a <Link> :
`<Link to="/{insurance.id}/edit" className="btn btn-sm btn-warning" >               EDIT </Link>`

Comment: Ok, i got it. The link was the problem instead i should've used <Link to={"/" + insurance.id + "/edit"} .... </Link> Now i get the id that i need, but the display is the same, only hello

Comment: Ok, this worked, thank you so much. I only have one problem. Even though `insurance.id` and `insuranceId` have the same value, the if doesn't work. I did an if statement to check, and this return false for every comparison: `const insurance = insurances.map(function(insurance) { if (insurance.id === insuranceId) return "true"; else return "false"; })`